# Highcharts line chart: point should be clickable, the line between the points not. Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linechart

I have a Highcharts line chart where the points need to be clickable, but the line between the points shouldn't (customer requirements...) - I couldn't find anything in the Highcharts API, neither here on stackoverflow. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of plugins, which allows do that.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! :-) That's what I was looking for!